Asure Timer Function using the isolated worker model
I'm new to using the isolated worker model in .NET8. I'm trying to create a new function that will execute daily at a specific time. I've spent several days looking at the documentation on how to use the isolated worker for a timer function but seem to be getting lost in the weeds. I tried the MS Learn example, but that is a http trigger. not sure how to set up the application for a timer trigger. Any help in where I might find a solution would be appreciated.
This is what I tried however when I run it locally it produces an URL that must be used in a browser to execute:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

static class ProcessCustomers
{
[Function(nameof(ProcessCustomerEmailAccounts))]
public static async Task<string> ProcessCustomerEmailAccounts([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
        // Calculate the next occurrence of 11:30 PM today
DateTime now = context.CurrentUtcDateTime;
DateTime nextScheduledTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 23, 30, 0);

if (now > nextScheduledTime)
{
    // If it's already past 11:30 PM today, schedule for tomorrow
    nextScheduledTime = nextScheduledTime.AddDays(1);
}

// Set the timer for the next occurrence
await context.CreateTimer(nextScheduledTime, CancellationToken.None);

    string result = "";
    result += await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo") + " ";
    result += await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London") + " ";
    result += await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle");
    return result;
}

[Function(nameof(SayHello))]
public static async Task<string> SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string cityName, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(SayHello));
    logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}", cityName);
    return await Task.FromResult($"Hello, {cityName}!");
}

[Function(nameof(StartProcessCustomerEmailAccounts))]
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> StartProcessCustomerEmailAccounts(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(StartProcessCustomerEmailAccounts));

    string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(ProcessCustomerEmailAccounts));
    logger.LogInformation("Created new orchestration with instance ID = {instanceId}", instanceId);

    return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
}

}

I finally figured it out:

I figured it out You need to change the trigger type in the Start Process remove the returns expected for an HTTP trigger:
{
    [Function(nameof(ProcessCustomerEmailAccounts))]
    public static async Task ProcessCustomerEmailAccounts([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        result += await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo") + " ";
        result += await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London") + " ";
        result += await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle");
        return;
    }

    [Function(nameof(SayHello))]
    public static async Task<string> SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string cityName, FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(SayHello));
        logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}", cityName);
        return await Task.FromResult($"Hello, {cityName}!");
    }

    [Function(nameof(StartProcessCustomerEmailAccounts))]
    public static async Task StartProcessCustomerEmailAccounts(
        [TimerTrigger("0 30 13 * * *")] TimerInfo timerInfo,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(StartProcessCustomerEmailAccounts));

        string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(ProcessCustomerEmailAccounts));
        logger.LogInformation("Created new orchestration with instance ID = {instanceId}", instanceId);

        return;
    }

}

